# Predictable Implies Progressive

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

If I define the predictable $\sigma$ algebra $\mathcal{P}_T$ in terms of the sets $(s,t]\times F$ for $0\leq s <t\leq T$ and $F \in \mathcal{F}_s$ (along with $\{0\}\times F, F\in \mathcal{F}_0$).  How do I infer that a $\mathcal{P}_T$ measurable process (say $X(t,\omega)$) is progressively measurable?  Is it sufficient to observe that the sets that generate $\mathcal{P}_T$,
$$
(s,t]\times F,\quad F\in \mathcal{F}_s\subset  \mathcal{F}_t
$$
are in $\mathcal{B}([0,t])\times \mathcal{F}_t$ (and analogously for $\{0\}\times F, F\in \mathcal{F}_0$)?  This would certainly imply that since the preimage of $X(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a predictable set, it can be constructed by sets of the above form, hence it is is also in $\mathcal{B}([0,t])\times \mathcal{F}_t$.  Is this sufficient, or is there more to the argument?

Comment: Well, essentially, yes. It's unclear to me what about the argument is unclear to you. What's your definition of progressive measurability?

Comment: Progressively measurable if, for any $t<T$, the process is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{B}([0,t])\times \mathcal{F}_t$.

Comment: Use the idea in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2990837/238946

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the generating system of $\mathcal{P}_T$ specified in your question. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the class of progressive processes. Then, by the functional monotone class theorem (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem#Monotone_class_theorem_for_functions)), $\mathcal{H}$ contains all bounded predictable processes. For a general predictable process, use that $X \wedge n$ is a predictable process increasing to $X$.